# Scalling site to mobile scale

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

How to make scaling div? (look screenshots)
i want to make background on all device this same scale.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NRPH.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmGSj.png)

I'm trying `<div class="col-xs-1">` and to div in css add background-size in % or give auto but dont work

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Please update your question to show what you have already tried, and explain the specific problem in a minimal, complete, and verifiable example.

Answer (score 0):

https://plnkr.co/edit/vtV1sxA85EKCUPlRpoRo?p=preview

the following properties makes your picture occupy the entire div on which the background is applied

```
background: #ffffff url("https://placebear.com/700/700") no-repeat 
center center fixed;
background-size:100% 100%;
```

let me know if it this is what you wanted